# Python fastest byte to string conversion

Tags: python

I need to convert a byte array to a string to send to an SPI device.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this ?

```
def writebytes(bytes):
  str = ""
  for i in bytes: str += chr(i)
  self.spi.transfer(str)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `"".join` with a generator expression.

```
def writebytes(bytes):
    self.spi.transfer("".join(chr(i) for i in bytes))
```

Comment: Actually, using generator expression is slower than using simple `"".join(map(char, bytes))` because when a generator expression is passed, `join` has to iterate over the results to get the total length of input and save them for later. When passing a list, the elements will be available anytime.